# Favorite questions and answers from last quarter of 2018

Tags: discussion

[image]

Recently while thinking about encouraging the quality Q/A and to keep enthusiasm and voting contribution, I came to know about idea of favorite questions and answers which was [introduced in 2014 on Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1355/51562). It's about posting your favorite questions and answers in *past quarter* of a year. Such a tradition has been working fine for 5 years on [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4415/51562) and on [Scifi.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12255).

So, Let's start!

**Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from October 1<sup>st</sup> 2018 through December 31<sup>th</sup> 2018.**

You can search all [questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3Aq+created%3A2018-10..2018-12) and [answers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa%20created%3a2018-10..2018-12) created in past 3 months and following are some useful [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) queries useful to effectively filter posts:

- [Questions with **best score** created within 3 month range](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/958811/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018%2F10%2F01)
- [Questions with **most View** created within 3 month range](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/958812/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018%2F10%2F01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/958813/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018%2F10%2F01)

However you can share your favorite questions and answers that you really enjoyed or found very useful and worth appreciating. You can also share Q/A posted by yourself that you think deserves appreciation.

Note: If you don't like this idea, you may downvote the question. If this idea is well received, we will continue at every quarter to keep the enthusiasm and to appreciate deserving efforts! :)

Answer (score 6):

There are some questions I liked this quarter. I would like to add a few questions I liked the most to the below list:

- [Which is the earliest reference to Upavedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/30117/5212)

  This question shows research effort by linking various articles from the internet. A very good candidate on showing what kind research should be done while posting a question.
- [On what basis are 4 mahavakyas chosen?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/30195/5212)

  A very good question about philosophy which asks with logic why can't be any other Mahavakyas which will give to more interesting answers.
- [Why was Shishupala born with three eyes and four arms?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29539/5212)

  I am interested in stories and mythology part of Hinduism. I know Shishupala's story but haven't thought in that direction why he was born in such a way. Way of thinking is appreciable.
- [What are Bhujanga stotrams?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29730/5212)

  I have heard the term Bhujanga stotrams and even listened to those stotras before this question was asked. But after this question is posted, I searched about it on the internet thoroughly and recalled the grammar I learnt in the past. That gave me an opportunity to know about more Sanskrit meters. As a result, I posted [an answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29826/5212) too. That question was helpful in understanding the prosody and beauty of Sanskrit and other ancient languages.

[On a side note, I found many questions which need either improvement in title or grammar or body while I was skimming through the search query provided in the question. Help in improving grammar, title will be appreciated.]

Comment: +1 Even I found that "What are Bhujanga stotrams?" interesting. had dig about it too.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings.