# Favorite questions and answers from 2nd quarter of 2019

Tags: discussion

Looking at the positive response from community, in the spirit of encouraging efforts of writing good questions and answers, We are continuing the tradition of [Favorite questions and answer from last quarter](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1632/277).

**Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from April 1<sup>st</sup> 2019 through June 3<sup>th</sup> 2019.**

You can search all [questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3Aq+created%3A2019-03..2019-06) and [answers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa%20created%3a2019-03..2019-06) created in past 3 months and following are some useful [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) queries useful to effectively filter posts:

- [Questions with **best score** created within 3 month range](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/958811/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019%2F04%2F01)
- [Questions with **most View** created within 3 month range](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/958812/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019%2F04%2F01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/958813/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019%2F04%2F01)

Besides sharing your favorite questions and answers that you really enjoyed or found very useful and worth appreciating, you can also share Q/A posted by yourself that you think deserves appreciation.

Comment: On (this) 5th anniversary of our site, we are thinking to start [Monthly Answer Challenges](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4417/51562). If you like this idea, upvote the comment.

Comment: Sorry but are all your ideas always copied from that site "Movies & TV"? Doesn't look good to me .. We are a different site, we have our own set of users. So, if needed, we should be able to come up with our own ideas rather than copying all the time other people's ideas

Comment: @Rickross feel free to propose/discuss your idea.

Comment: I don't have any ideas but that doesn't mean I will be copying others.

Comment: @Rickross Idea is to motivate for answers, no necessity to copy the theme as it is. We can have our own theme for that :)

Comment: I don't doubt your intention, it must be good only but pls don't bring everything from that site over here :) Also to be frank I don't understand how it is good, It just gives few users to express why they have found certain posts great ..Now we can already chk who has what posts as favorites .. so only thing new here is their explanations why they have found them as great but why shd others bother to see their explanations .. moreover some people might feel why my posts are not included in anybody's favorites, anyways, that is my opinion, others will have different opinions obviously.

Comment: @Rickross Not necessarily Movies & TV, other sites like Science fiction and Fantasy followed the same idea. Even though we are different in scope, meta works same and many successful policies are borrowed from other sites like Christianity and Islam. .

Comment: @Pandya Who will award bounties?

Answer (score 5):

Among questions:

1. My favorite question would be [Guru Shishya relationship](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34234/647) . The question was posted with good intent of receiving answers from all various sects since any sect existence is because Guru-Shishya sampradaya only. However it did not match the expectations yet. Hoping to receive more answers; This question'll help others to know how important this relationship is in spiritual evolution of a sAdhaka.
2. Another question would be [How did the concept of 'Sect' arise in Sanatana Dharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34331/647)
    ; This question posted in a intent to understand how sectarian things started in sanatana dharma.
3. This question is helpful for anyone who wants to study Vedas and which interpretation they can choose to start with: [Which are the methodologies for interpreting Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35312/647)
4. Another question which I feel was good [Why is Shiva and Parvati depicted with their children but not Vishnu and Lakshmi?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/35068/647)

Among answers:

1. [Does Tantra say cow is sacred animal?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34917/647)
2. [Which are the methodologies for interpreting Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35312/647)

Answer (score 4):

Questions:

- [What to do when scriptures go against conscience?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34832/277) Conscience play important role in beliefs manytimes I think. Mostly when people believe in particular philosophy or doctrine it is due to their conscience math with that philosophy. Also it happens that you don't agree with some of the points of scripture or philosophy you believe in. So, this question is important regarding how to deal with this issue.
- [How did the concept of 'Sect' arise in Sanatana Dharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34331/277) We know that there are several sects called Sampradaya in Hinduism. And mostly people following Sanatan Dharma are associated with or belong to particular Sampradaya. So, knowing the concept, purpose and importance of Sampradaya is important.
- [Where is the concept of Prapatti/Saranagati mentioned in the mukhya upanishads, as per the Sri Vaishnava interpretation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34416/277) Sharanagati is very great concept of Sri Vaishnavism who believes that it is a way to Moksha better than other paths. So, verifying its basis in Mukhya Upanishads is important thing.
- [Do Dvaitins, Vishistadvaitins and Achintya-Bheda-Abheda-vaadins consider the dream world as real?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34916/277) This is yet another important philosophical question which deals with one of the states viz. Jagrit, Swapna, Sushupti and Turiya.
- [What is the story of origin of Yoga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34342/277) Yoga is one popular Darshan along with Vedanta in the group of six Astika philosophies. So, knowing the story behind Patanjali's writing Darshana Sutras is interesting.

Answers:

<sup>Note: Currently I'm posting self answers only which I'm aware of. Need to go through other several answers to list; will update the list later.</sup>

- [Methodologies for interpreting Vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35312/277) Vedas are the prime scripture of SanAtana Dharma on which whole Dharma is based; hence interpreting Vedas is a significant issue.
- [10 Characteristics of brAhmanas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35340/277). I've been looking for [a scriptural source that introduce brAhmanas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19151/277). So, I liked sharing this.